# Java LibGDX BitmapFont setScale method not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently trying to scale a font but I am receiving the error 
"the method setScale(float, float) is undefined for the type BitmapFont"
This is the code section where I am getting the error, specifically in lines 2 and 4.

```
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("text.fnt"));
    font.setScale (.25f, -.25f);
    shadow = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("shadow.fnt"));
    shadow.setScale (.25f -.25f);
```

I created the variables here

```
  public static  BitmapFont font;
public  static BitmapFont shadow;
```

When I check other examples of using the setScale function, this seems to be the format used. Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Use butmap font data and values bigger then 0.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This method doesn't exist anymore in the [BitmapFont](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) class.

An [API change](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/CHANGES) for the Bitmap* classes has been introduced with LibGDX 1.5.6 (released in April 2015) as explained in this [libgdx team blog post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658).
The tutorial you followed is probably now outdated.

Long story short, with the latest libgdx version, you should be able to do :

```
font.getData().setScale(.25f,.25f);
```